# Returning item IDs as key values instead of list of objects in a CRUD web API: thoughts?

Tags: json, httpresponse, api-design

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have an API to a resource that stores simple items representing cards with text. Their IDs are set by the user on creation and we want to keep them as object for the possibility of adding more properties in the future.

We have following items:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "card_0000",
        "text": "Opportunities don't happen, you create them.",
    },
    {
        "id": "card_0001",
        "text": "Just one small positive thought in the morning can change your whole day.",
    }
]
```

`GET /cards` can return either:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "cards": [
            {
                "id": "card_0000",
                "text": "Opportunities don't happen, you create them.",
            },
            {
                "id": "card_0001",
                "text": "Just one small positive thought in the morning can change your whole day.",
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

or:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "cards": {
            "card_0000": {"text": "Opportunities don't happen, you create them."},
            "card_0001": {"text": "Just one small positive thought in the morning can change your whole day."},
        }
    }
}
```

Now the thing is that the first option seems to be much more common and also much easier to document in common standards like OpenAPI.

However, it seems to me that the second option is much more versatile, because I can still iterate through the objects, and on top of that I can also easily access particular items or check for their existence using the ID (which I know, because as a user I have set them). On the other side, `GET /cards/{cardId}` could fulfill that function for the cost of broadband.

I'd like to see some opinions on this matter. Should dynamic keys in API responses be generally avoided? What are some other reasons?

Answer (score 0):

You can not provide the resources in a specific order if using a key-value pair instead of an array to represent a collection of resources.

The order of keys of an object is *not* guaranteed by JSON standard:

> An object is an **unordered collection** of zero or more name/value pairs [...]
>
> JSON parsing libraries have been observed to differ as to whether or not they make the ordering of object members visible to calling software. Implementations whose behavior does not depend on member ordering will be interoperable in the sense that they will not be affected by these differences.

If your API should support sorting of resource collections, I would use an array.

Answer (score 0):

An array gives more flexibility on the order of the results without forcing the consuming application to change how it processes the list. Your example is assuming sort by id or perhaps *forcing* a sort-by-id whereas you may want to sort or filter on another field. The array approach also allows for metadata covering things like the sort order, stats, number of items, or other relevant data about the whole return payload.

It could also facilitate scenarios where your api gives options to select the fields available in the return payload. By always returning the array in the same way you simplify consumption and documentation - in my opinion :-)